Shadow Imaging of satellites can produce sub-meter resolution images while satellites are in GSO. How would this information be used?
At 36,000km altitude, GSO satellites are beyond the distance at which their structure can be resolved by conventional ground based photography. However, it is theoretically possible to obtain high resolution images of satellites using their ground shadow when they eclipse a star.
Because of their enormous distance, stars can be considered point light sources. The shadow of a GSO satellite cast by a single star forms a diffraction pattern on the surface of the earth. An array of detectors aligned along the ground track of the satellite's shadow can be used to observe the diffraction pattern, then reconstruct the silhouette of the satellite.

The illustration above shows the shadow ground tracks of a single satellite from multiple stars on a single night

From https://amostech.com/TechnicalPapers/2016/Poster/Douglas.pdf

Earth based shadow observations remain the most accurate method to
calculate an asteroid’s size and shape other than measurements made
from venturing spacecraft in the solar system. Techniques have been
developed to study distant objects in the Kuiper Belt and Oort Cloud
using serendipitous observations of stellar occultations.
Shadow imaging fundamentally differs from conventional imaging in that
as the collection apertures get smaller the attainable resolution
increases. Furthermore, all past efforts indicate that shadow imaging
is very resilient to atmospheric turbulence.
Sub-meter image resolution is shown to be readily achievable in
foreseeable shadow collection attempts.

How would this information be used? Other than identifying gross structural anomalies such as an undeployed solar panel, what useful information could this technique provide?

Sub-meter resolution is possible with asteroids because the duration of the occultations is usually several seconds, and the frame rate is fast enough to get to that resolution. If I did my calculation correctly, a 100 m geosat at 36E6 m would occult a star for 0.04 seconds. Probably not long enough to get sub-meter resolution.

Can you clarify whether the question is actually "Why would you want an image of a satellite?" like the title would indicate? The body doesn't have a question at all.

@jpa ...  the question is "How would this information be used?"

@Woody Thanks for the clarified question. I felt (and the only answer seems to agree) that the "how" by itself is ambiguous between "by what method" and "for what purpose".

When you illuminate an object with a plane wave, you do not get a crisp shadow 36,000 km away, youget a messy diffraction pattern.


Figure 3: Irradiance pattern of first spectral bin for simulation Case 1B, with bin width of 100 nm. Left: True ground
irradiance pattern. Right: Measurement inferred ground irradiance pattern. Displayed images represent only the center
28 x 28 m region of the full 100 x 100 m support plane to better illustrate the intensity fluctuations. Color bars are in
units of W/m^2

from Shadow Imaging of Geosynchronous Satellites: Simulation, Image
Reconstruction, and Shadow Prediction (also archived)
You would have to collect the diffraction pattern's footprint over hundreds of meters to reconstruct the satellite.
And you have wait for the occultation event, weather, atmospheric seeing to coincide and collect your data in milliseconds or less.
And if you are going to do that kind of elaborate experiment, then you might as well use bright reflected sunlight rather than dim diffracted starlight. Then you can collect data at almost any time during any clear night for as long as you like. More statistics, better quality imaging.

At 36,000km altitude, GSO satellites are beyond the distance at which their structure can be resolved by conventional ground based photography.

So use unconventional photography = interferometry + wavefront correction!
In Astronomy SE:

Can the interferometer called "Gravity" measure "a few centimeters on the Moon"? Answer: "At a distance of 400,000 km this translates to 6 m(eter resolution".
Will the Magdalena Ridge Optical Interferometer be able to image extended objects like the surface of the Moon? Answer: "This is sufficient to have of the order of 1 meter resolution at the Moon's distance..." and links to Wired.com's August 29, 2019 How America's Spooks Seek to Spy on Distant Satellites (also archived)

Note that the resolution of the Very Large Telescope is 0.002 arcsecond, which at 36,000 km is only 35 cm.
Other than being a means to get some SBIRs and a few papers published, I don't see any advantages of stellar occultation measurements as discussed here, over just doing interferometry of reflected light as the above-linked Wired article discusses.

Magdalena Ridge Observatory (MRO) interferometer:


Magdalena Ridge Observatory Interferometer computer graphic overlay of the BCF building and the ten telescopes Source

Lowell Observatory from Wired:


Lowell Observatory in Flagstaff, Arizona, hosts one of the few existing optical interferometers - a multitelescope instrument that can snap pictures of objects in geosynchronous Earth orbit. Credit: Lowell Observatory


The title question seems to be "why would you want an image of a satellite", not "how to take an image of a satellite".

@jpa No, I think that "Why would you want shadow Imaging of satellites?" is a better description of the title, and my answer is that "You wouldn't; you would want ground imaging and solar illumination". Of course you might also want imaging from nearby spacecraft with spy telescopes too, but that's going to be a different question post.

@jpa  but certainly if someone came along and wrote an answer to "Why would you want an image of a satellite in GEO?" it would also be well-received, and someone could also choose to ask that as a new question, explaining that there are several ways to do it.

In early research like this, not all possible applications are known yet.
The paper itself gives the one reason that you mention also:

If a malfunction
occurs upon orbit insertion such as a solar panel not deploying or an antenna getting snagged there is no direct way to
observe it from Earth in finely resolved detail.

Especially if the technique could be extended to non-geosynchronous satellites, there are several other applications:

Identifying space debris
Intelligence about satellites launched by foreign states
Identifying problems such as uncontrolled tumbling after orbit insertion

